# how to start a ToDo App when call ends?

Tags: android

I am trying to develop a ToDo application which helps user make notes as soon as call ends. In general life we are told many things to be done on phone. For example : buy grocery on way back to office.

I am facing difficulty in starting this application. I am using BroadcastReceiver How should I implement onReceive() method?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Yor code is welcome as well.

Comment: What kind of broadcast receiver? When is it triggered?

Answer (score 0):

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.your"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">

    <receiver android:name=".CallTracker">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

</application>
```

BroadcasrReceiver

```
public class CallTracker extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();


}
```

}

Look for the 'state' in the bundle. When the state changes from OFFHOOK to IDLE start your application.

From activity you can use this [example](http://www.truiton.com/2014/08/android-phonestatelistener-example/)

Comment: @Risbabh Is this help you ?